# Stackdriver failing to create alert based on custom metric

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I have the following advanced log query:

```
resource.type="container"
resource.labels.cluster_name="my-cluster"
resource.labels.namespace_id="mynamespace"
"SOMESTRING"
```

which when executed fetches the expected results.

I create a custom metric based on this query.

Then I select "Create Alert from Metric" (`my-custom-metric`) and try to set up an alert.

When finished an trying to save the alerting policy, I get the following error:

> Error 400: Field alert_policy.conditions[0].condition_threshold.filter had an invalid value of “metric.type=“logging.googleapis.com/user/my-custom-metric” resource.type=“container”“: The filter contains unknown resource type: container

How is this even possible?

Stackdriver itself filled in the resource type automatically when I selected

> Create Alert from Metric

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this error message  is the use of the Legacy Stackdriver in Kubernetes [1].

In the Legacy Kubernetes Stackdriver, GCP have 2 different resources types for Kubernetes;

1- gke_container; used for metrics only

2- container; used for Logs only

In the new version of Stackdriver, GCP only has 1 resource type named “k8s_container” including metrics and the logs. That means using this new version will fix the issue definitively.

The new Stackdriver version is enabled by default on Kubernetes 1.14+ but you can change it manually as mentioned in this documentation [2][3] if you using a different version.

However, as workaround, you can simply delete the red tainted resource type into Stackdriver workspace and add “gke_container” instead. That worked for me.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/migration#what-is-changing

[2] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/installing#migrating

[3] https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/kubernetes-engine/migration#upgrade-timeline